# Why are my site's images not recognized by Facebook?

Tags: asp.net, image, facebook

Here's the object debugger for one of the pages: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elon.edu%2Fe-net%2FNote.aspx%3Fid%3D954246

Notice the image box is empty, but when I click on it, the image opens just fine in every browser I could test. The image is served by an .ashx handler by asp.net with a content type of "image/jpeg". Any ideas why Facebook doesn't recognize any image served by my application? This causes all facebook posts to display without an image, which we want to avoid for aesthetic reasons. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the HTTP headers for the image and you'll see that you're sending a 404 HTTP status back with the image.

```
telnet www.elon.edu 80

GET /e-net/Image.ashx?w=298&crop=true&id=28213 HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.elon.edu
```

.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 14248
Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2011 19:55:22 GMT
```

**EDIT**

I don't know if the 404 is causing the error but that's where I'd start.

**EDIT2**

Based on your comments I'm guessing you've got something like this in your handler, right:

```
        try
        {
            //Logic here
            //..
            Response.End();
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
```

If so, your problem is `Response.End()` which actually throws a `ThreadAbortException` which is absolutely not what you were expecting probably. There's a [couple](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx) of [different](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/721/using-responseredirect-and-responseend-in-trycatch-block/) things [you](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) can do, I'll let you read up on it and make your own choice.

Comment: I would hazard that the 404 is almost certainly causing the error

Comment: Indeed it is... Will mark as answer as soon as SO lets me. I'll dig into things, but may have a followup question of why my context.Response.StatusCode is reached, even though it's only inside of my catch block, and the image seems to be serving without error... Regardless, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @ElonU Webdev, see my **EDIT2** above

Comment: A Server.Transfer() to a static image file was throwing the ThreadAbortException that you correctly identified as my root problem. Thanks for your help.